# FIRDatabaseQuery не возвращает значение

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

Ребята, мне необходимо вернуть значение Int, полученное из базы данных, но так как у меня Firebase делает асинхронный метод, то значение возвращается нулевое. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как можно изменить данный блок кода?

```
func blueRewardPercent() -> Int {
        let userRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        var rewardPercent : Int = 0
        let purchaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Reward/\(userRef!)")
        purchaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "systemLastLogin").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            let dataSnapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            rewardPercent = dataSnapshot["rewardCardPercent"] as! Int!
            // Здесь нужно сделать return
        })

        return rewardPercent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, `rewardPercent` Вы возвращаете прежде, чем получаете данные. Измените, к примеру, так:

```
func blueRewardPercent(completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let userRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    var rewardPercent : Int = 0
    let purchaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Reward/\(userRef!)")
    purchaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "systemLastLogin").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        let dataSnapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        rewardPercent = dataSnapshot["rewardCardPercent"] as! Int!
        // Здесь нужно сделать return
        completion(rewardPercent)
    })
}
```

и обращаетесь:

```
blueRewardPercent { (rewardPercent) in
    print(rewardPercent)
}
```